# UK Standard application - need to send documents - can I purchase the return label from UPS store?

Tags: vfs-global

Have been trying hard to use the VFS website - can I purchase the return label from any UPS store and send the package or does it HAVE to be from the VFS website?- which btw is very difficult to use